# How to fill `missings` in a vector using next valid observation

Tags: julia, imputation

Is there any specific function for filling `missings` in an array?
MWE:

```
x = [missing,missing,2,3,missing,4]
desired = [2,2,2,3,4,4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up with this solution, however, I wish `accumulate!` has reverse option:

```
function bf!(x)
   init = x[end]
   @inbounds for i in reverse(eachindex(x))
       ismissing(x[i]) ? x[i] = init : init = x[i]
   end
   x
end
```

Comment: You can use `@view x[end:-1:begin]` for a non-allocating reverse.

Comment: `views` in Julia are great, but I guess for this problem, you will need at least one `reverse` with allocation.

Comment: `accumulate!((last, x) -> ismissing(x) ? last : x, @view(xs[end:-1:begin]), @view(xs[end:-1:begin])).parent` should not allocate for the array.

Comment: Nevertheless, your loop is much clearer code. I'd just write it with `for i in reverse(eachindex(x))`.

Answer (score 4):

that functionality isn't in the Base language, but it is in [Impute.jl](https://github.com/invenia/Impute.jl). What you are looking is known as *Next Observation carried Backward* Imputation (`nocb`). you can do that with that julia package in the following way:

```
using Impute (if you don't have the package in your enviroment, add it)
x = [missing,missing,2,3,missing,4]
y = copy(x)
Impute.nocb!(x) #implace, overwrites x
z = Impute.nocb(y) #creates a new vector
```

it also has other forms of data imputation, so if you are going to impute tabular data, that's the most secure way.

you could also implement your own `nocb`. this is the implementation used by Impute.jl, with some simplifications:

```
#implace version
function nocb!(data::AbstractVector{Union{T, Missing}}) where T
    @assert !all(ismissing, data)
    end_idx = findlast(!ismissing, data)
    count = 1
    for i in end_idx - 1:-1:firstindex(data)
        if ismissing(data[i])
            data[i] = data[i+1]
        else
            end_idx = i
            count = 1
        end
    end
    return data
end
#out of place version
nocb(x) = nocb!(copy(x))
```

Comment: The `Impute` package performance is not acceptable, however, I came up with a function.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know one, but you can always create one:

```
for i in 1:length(array)
    if array[i] === missing
        array[i] = 1 # whatever you choose
    end 
end
```

Note: when you println out the type of new array, you see
`Vector{Union{Missing, Int64}}`

Comment: It doesn't help, since I want the next valid observation be used for filling.